# jQuery .show() a flex box

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I have an element with a flexbox

```
<ul id="myFlexbox">

div#myFlexbox{
    display:flex;
}
```

after hide it and show it, it gets messed up.

```
$('#myFlexbox').show();
```

now the element has a display of block instead of flex.

```
<ul id="myFlexbox" style="display: block;">
```

How can I use .hide and .show with flexboxes?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The `show()` adds `display:block` as a default for `div`. You can change the `display` to `flex` using jQuery `css()`:

```
$('#myFlexbox').css('display', 'flex');
```

Comment: This creates a hardcoded link between your JS and your css. Now if you decide to change your css so that #myFlexbox is no longer a flex, your JS is incorrect. I prefer mxlse's answer.

Comment: This does not support the duration parameter.

Comment: Look at the excellent solution of Nikolay (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559345/760777). You can stil use show() and hide() and you do not have to change your javascript code.

Answer (score 48):

JQuery `.show()` doesn't know about your `display: flex;` (not flexbox). Instead try to add and remove a hiding class.

CSS:

```
#myFlexbox{
  display: flex;
}

.hide{
  display: none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#myFlexbox').addClass('hide');
$('#myFlexbox').removeClass('hide');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p2msLqtt/

Otherwise you have to execute your JS after the CSS is completely loaded and DOM is ready I guess - i.e. like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- CSS -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- BODY PART -->
    <!-- SCRIPT TO HIDE AND SHOW -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Updated the fiddle and set Javascript execution to domready - it's working:

https://jsfiddle.net/p2msLqtt/1/

Comment: This does not support the duration parameter.

Answer (score 19):

just use

```
.class{display: none}

.class[style*='display: block']{
    display: flex !important;
}
```

when jquery add styl attribut css will be applied, works perfectly on Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: I think this is the best solution since it allows you to continue using show(). Simple CSS change which doesn't require a bunch of js changes to check for the current state. Really nice idea!

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 8):

The idea is to create a custom function `showFlex()` similar to jQuery `show()` and call it with the element which need to have the `display:flex;` property.

**jQuery Solution**

```
$.fn.showFlex = function() {
  this.css('display','flex');
}
```

`$('#myFlexbox').showFlex();`

**JavaScript Solution**

```
Object.prototype.showFlex = function() {
    this.style.display = 'flex';
}
```

`document.getElementById('myFlexbox').showFlex();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: jQuery solution should be
`$.fn.showFlex = function(){
 this.css({'display':'flex'});
}`

Answer (score 7):

I know it is a little too late (3 years) but this is the way I managed to do it.

I created a rule in css for my div, for example #myDiv, that goes like this

```
#myDiv[style*='block'] {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

It takes advantage of what jQuery does to the DOM, it applies 'display:block'. I used inline-flex because i needed it for what i'm doing, but it can be whatever you want. In this way the rule goes faster applied without any flickering.

Answer (score 6):

Since other answers did not account for the possibility that you might be using the `duration` argument...

**Short Answer:** Use [.hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) for hiding the value and that shouldn't happen.

**A little explanation:**

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), **except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value**. If an element has a display value of *flex* and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed *flex*.

<sub>From documentation, Changed 'inline' to 'flex' to fit the contenxt!</sub>

So **jQuery** knows what you're hiding! If you've hidden it using [.hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) that is, And it knows how to show it again with the right display value.

Comment: This is great, but how do you deal with the "flashing" that can occur. Because the page loads with the element visible it's on screen for a second before it "hides". In the past that's why I would always default the CSS to `display:none` and then use the `.show()` method to bring it into view.

Comment: Hmmm, the first thing that come to mind is just to use a wrapper with display:none value until the page loads...

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap your `display: flex` content with an element.

```
<div id="flexWrapper">
    <ul id="myFlexbox"></ul>
</div>
```

bind your javascript show/hide to '#flexWrapper'

Answer (score 3):

The `class` solution works, yes. 
Here's a different approach I came up with:

#### Javascript Function

```
function showFlex(element) {

    var flexContainer = document.getElementById(element);

    flexContainer.setAttribute("style", "display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex;");
}
```

#### To use it:

```
showFlex( "yourIDhere" );
```

> Note that the ID doesn't need the # when you call the function.

#### Example:

https://codepen.io/florantara/pen/aLeyYb/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myFlexbox').show({
    start: function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'flex');
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try  `$(this).show().css('display', 'flex');`

Show it normally and set it back to `flex`